# DESIGN -- Remove by name or object?

Tags: c#, c++

Does it make more sense to remove an object using its name/id or passing the actual object?  For example:

```
void MyList::remove(MyObject &myObject) { /* blah */ }
// or
void MyList::remove(std::string id) { /* blah */ }
```

I've used both but I can't really see what the advantages vs disadvantages.  Is there a preferred standard?

EDIT:  this would probably be a better example providing what I'm trying to do:

Let's say I have an Account class with a collection of Transactions.  Am I better to pass Transaction object or the id of the Tranaction?

```
class Account
{
  private List<Transaction> transaction = new List<Transaction>();

  public void Remove(Transaction transaction) { }
  // OR
  public void Remove(string name) { }
  // OR
  public void Remove(Guid id) { }
}
```

NOTE: this question has both C++ and C# code...

Comment: If you want to emulate the standard library you would use an iterator.

Comment: Providing a method to search by name isn't very generic, especially if your list class is templated on the element type where the objects may not have names.

Comment: @keelerjr12 What about c#? Your question is tagged c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not have the item reference always. So it is better to have remove methods by name or id.
You can decide which one is preferable (name or id) according to your business requirement. name or id has to be unique otherwise it will remove the wrong item. So the business requirement has to decide it.

Comment: You could use a find(Guid id) function to get the actual object and then pass that...

Comment: But it easy to user class call method Remove(Guid id), rather find the item and then remove it.